# Why this append function in python didn't work out?

Tags: python

```
def random_row(board, length):
    return randint(0, len(board) - length)


def random_col(board, length):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - length)

ship_all = []

for length in range(1,6):
    ship = []
    ship_row = random_row(board, length)
    ship.append(ship_row)
    ship_col = random_col(board, length)
    ship.append(ship_col)
    i = 0
    if randint(0,1) == 0:
        while i<length:
            ship_all.append(ship)
            ship[0] += 1
            print ship
            i+=1
    else:
        while i<length:
            ship_all.append(ship)
            ship[1] += 1
            print ship
            i+=1

print ship_all
```

The ship_all.append(ship) just give the final result of the ship, but print ship works out correctly, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Because you're filling `ship_all` with *multiple references to the same list*. Move `ship = []` *inside* the `while` loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding copies of `ship` to `ship_all`, you are adding the *same list object* over and over again, altering that object each iteration.

Create a [copy of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python) each time you append:

```
ship_all.append(ship[:])
```

or create the `ship` list from scratch inside the `while` loops.

Comment: Thanks! It worked out, but the why, what does `ship[:]` stands for?

Comment: @Liye: It creates a copy by slicing the list from start to end, copying across all elements. You can also use `list(ship)`.